# Moving an entire wordpress site from one domain to a new domain and database

Tags: database, sql

I have done all the steps requiered to import the dump.sql file to new database, and copiey the entire content from the old domain over to the new one.

When i login to mydomain/wp-admin, i'm redirected back to the frontpage of the old domain, and can't access my control panel. I've followed all the steps for setting it up to the new domain, but i can't figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

First add

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
```

To your wp-config.php file (obviously change example.com to your domain)

then login and once you see the admin panel navigate to `http://yoursite/wp-admin/options.php`

there you can change `home` and `siteurl` to your new domain and save.

You will also need to change the links for images and other media in your post database table.

Comment: +1, Your answer was a lifesaver.  However, editing those two items on the `options.php` page does not work.  You get a options "saved" confirmation, but they still show up as the old values when the `options.php` page is reloaded.  I had to locate those two values in the database table and edit them manually.

Answer (score 2):

Update URLs in the database, re: [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

and/or, [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.